# How to determine the language of a RESX file

Tags: c#, localization, resx

I've read something from the web, and it makes me confused.

The .resx file (comes from any applications) can be:

1. + 'Language' + '.' +  + '.resX'  (ex: Word.fr-CA.resx)
2. or just "Word.resx"

Then how can I determine the language of a resx file when I open I the program?

There is no tag or element like "xml:lang" in the resx file.

Should I use the "extension" of the file to decide its language-locale?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is purely done by naming conventions,

- Word.fr-CA.resx or any similar is for fr-CA (the culture).
- Word.resx is the neutral one, which should match the culture defined in `[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute]`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhz003sc.aspx